# runtime error : running java class file

Tags: java, javac

I have download a simple java example from the net.I am trying to compile the code given below

```
package ArrayList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimpleArrayListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create an ArrayList object
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        /*
        Add elements to Arraylist using
        boolean add(Object o) method. It returns true as a general behavior
        of Collection.add method. The specified object is appended at the end
        of the ArrayList.
         */
        arrayList.add("1");
        arrayList.add("2");
        arrayList.add("3");

        /*
        Use get method of Java ArrayList class to display elements of ArrayList.
        Object get(int index) returns and element at the specified index in
        the ArrayList
         */
        System.out.println("Getting elements of ArrayList");
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(0));
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(1));
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(2));
    }
}
```

I have edited the program as per your suggestion and I can compile and I got the class file.

```
java SimpleArrayListExample.java
```

NOw I am trying to execute the file using

```
java -classpath . ArrayList.SimpleArrayListExample.java
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I google and found out that I have to specify -classpath .

> http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/826/java-exception-in-thread-main-javalangnoclassdeffounderror/  that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you try what the compiler suggested, "Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked"?

Comment: (-1) *Please search for the error message before asking a question* - try `arraylist unchecked or unsafe operation`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947806/unsafe-or-unchecked-operations-for-arraylist , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning

Comment: It should be `ArrayList<String> arrayList` for the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is *warning* that the type contained within the collection has not been declared.
You can use generics to emilinate this warning

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Edit:**

There is a problem with your package structure. The `SimpleArrayListExample` is not in a directory called `ArrayList`. To fix

- Move `SimpleArrayListExample.java` to a new directory called `ArrayList`.
- Compile using:- `javac ArrayList/SimpleArrayListExample.java`
- To Run: `java ArrayList.SimpleArrayListExample`

Note package names typically use *lowercase*.

Comment: even that doesn't seem to work.I tried that and got the same error. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics to avoid this warning:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create an ArrayList object
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //...
}
```

You could also suppress the warning if you don't want to use generics:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated question.with your suggestion I get a different error

Comment: Ah, make sure you put the generic declaration in the correct spot: ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 2):

Restrict your collection by providing the generic type for your collections or in other words make your collection **type safe**(compile time only) and the warning will disappear

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

also from **Java 7** due to inroduction of **Type Inference**

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a compilation error; rather, it is a *compilation warning*. This means that it will still compile, but it is recommended that the warning be fixed.

In this case, it's because your `ArrayList` is lacking a generic type. You should declare it as an `ArrayList<String>` instead, since you're only adding strings to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make it an `ArrayList<String>`.

This is called a *generic collection*, which means it's a collection that can be parameterized with a type, to store and retrieve objects of that type.

So, if you specify you want it to store `String`, the compiler will know that it returns `String` too. If you don't specify anything, it essentially falls back to `Object`, which means it can store anything (non-scalar) and retrieve anything (which, in turn, makes the compiler jumpy).

Comment: what is the difference between ArrayList and ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, but a warning.

It's caused because you are using ArrayList without a generic type.

You may want to read more about generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/