# DFS implementation error?

Tags: java, runtime-error, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am using dfs algorithm to implement from *geeksforgeeks.org*   [link here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/)

but when ever i have tried to run on compiler it is giving this error

> Note: p1_dfs.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

**YES I HAVE SEARCHED FOR IT !**
AND GET SOLUTION HERE [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947806/unsafe-or-unchecked-operations-for-arraylist)

BUT its not working I have changed generic type of list but not getting correct.

```
// Constructor
Graph(int v)
{
    V = v;
    adj = new LinkedList<Integer>[v];
    for (int i=0; i<v; ++i)
        adj[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
}
```

Comment: What you have changed shouldn't matter, although preferred way, but that is not what is causing the error. Anyway, I managed to run the same code using java 1.8, and it executed in first go.

Comment: @coolgirl you have mistaken something code may be run but will show this compilation error in extra

Comment: @coolgirl u can checkk out her    http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/iM0r5l

Comment: My IDE isn't complaining of any compilation errors TBH.

Comment: okk @coolgirl check out above link

Comment: Yea, it shows up there. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749904/1004631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Its an error(not actually) generate by compier.
So. Leave it and Run Program. :)